Errors with MLP neural network made from scratch trained on MNIST dataset
I'm experimenting with neural networks and decided to create an MLP from scratch to classify digits based on the MNIST training dataset. The MNIST data set I'm using is in the csv format and downloaded from here
I understand that my code is very inefficient as I don't support any batching or parallelization(this is just a rough first run through to get a better understanding before making it efficient) but I don't understand why it would make it as inaccurate as it currently is. I was hoping if there were any obvious errors I made in my MLP code below.
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import time
import pickle

class Parameter:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.grad = 0
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

class Neuron:
    def __init__(self, inputs):
        self.bias = Parameter(random.uniform(-1, 1))
        self.weights = [Parameter(random.uniform(-1, 1)) for i in range(inputs)]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"weight={self.weights}, bias={self.bias}"

class Layer:
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputs):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.neurons = [Neuron(inputs) for _ in range(outputs)]

    def __str__(self):
        str = ""
        for i in range(len(self.neurons)):
            str+=f"neuron {i+1}-\n{self.neurons[i]}\n"
        return str

class MLP:
    def __init__(self, inputs, hidden, output, activation, loss):
        if(len(hidden)==0):
            self.layers = [Layer(inputs, output)]
        else:
            self.layers = [Layer(inputs, (hidden[0]))]
            if(len(hidden)==1):
                self.layers += [Layer(hidden[0], output)]
            else:
                self.layers += [Layer(input, output) for input, output in zip(hidden, hidden[1:])] 
                self.layers += [Layer(hidden[-1], output)]

        self.activation_func = activation
        self.loss_func = loss
        
    def forward(self, input, label):
        inputs = input.copy()
        z = []
        a = []
        
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            unactivated = []
            activated = []
            for neuron in self.layers[i].neurons:
                w = [item.val for item in neuron.weights]
                val = np.dot(w, inputs) + neuron.bias.val
                unactivated.append(val)

                activated.append(self.activation_func[i](val))
            
            inputs = activated.copy()
            a.append(activated)
            z.append(unactivated)
        
        # a[-1] = MLP.normalize(a[-1])
                
        self.z = z
        self.a = a
        # print(f"z: {self.z}, a: {self.a}")

        self.loss = self.loss_func(a[-1], label)
        # print(f"\nLoss: {self.loss}")
        self.input = input
        self.label = label
        self.output = a[-1]
    
    def backward(self, learning_rate):

        for layer in self.layers:
            for neuron in layer.neurons:
                for weight in neuron.weights:
                    weight.grad = 0
                neuron.bias.grad = 0

        in_da = []
        for i in range(len(self.layers[-1].neurons)):
            in_da.append(self.loss_func(self.a[-1][i], self.label[i], deriv=True))

        for i in range(len(self.layers)-1, -1, -1):
            next_da = [0 for i in range(len(self.layers[i-1].neurons))]
            for n in range(len(self.layers[i].neurons)):
                dz = in_da[n] * self.activation_func[i](self.z[i][n], deriv=True)
                
                if(i==0):
                    dw = np.multiply(dz, self.input)
                else:   
                    dw = np.multiply(dz, self.a[i-1])
                
                db = dz

                for w in range(len(self.layers[i].neurons[n].weights)):
                    self.layers[i].neurons[n].weights[w].grad += dw[w]
                    if i>0:
                        next_da[w] += dz * self.layers[i].neurons[n].weights[w].val

                self.layers[i].neurons[n].bias.grad += db
                
            in_da = next_da.copy()

        # for i in range(len(self.layers)):
        #     print(f"LAYER {i}: \n")
        #     for n in range(len(self.layers[i].neurons)):
        #         print(f"Neuron {n}:")
        #         str = "weights: ["
        #         for w in self.layers[i].neurons[n].weights:
        #             str+=f"{w.grad}, "
        #         print(f"{str[:-2]}], bias: {self.layers[i].neurons[n].bias.grad}") 
        #     print()

        for layer in self.layers:
            for neuron in layer.neurons:
                for weight in neuron.weights:
                    weight.val -= learning_rate * weight.grad
                neuron.bias.val -= learning_rate * neuron.bias.grad
    
    def run(self, input):
        inputs = input.copy()
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            activated = []
            for neuron in self.layers[i].neurons:
                w = [item.val for item in neuron.weights]
                val = np.dot(w, inputs) + neuron.bias.val
                
                activated.append(self.activation_func[i](val))
            
            inputs = activated.copy()
        
        return MLP.normalize(activated)
        
    def mean_square(x, label, deriv=False):
        return 2 * (x - label) if deriv else sum(np.subtract(x, label) ** 2)

    def relu(x, deriv=False):
        return float(np.greater(x, 0)) if deriv else max(0, x)

    def tanh(x, deriv=False):
        return 1 - (math.tanh(x) ** 2) if deriv else math.tanh(x)

    def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
        return MLP.sigmoid(x) * (1 - MLP.sigmoid(x)) if deriv else 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
    
    def normalize(x):
        if all(item == 0 for item in x):
            return x
        val = sum(x)
        return [item/val for item in x]
    
    def __str__(self):
        str = ""
        for i in range(len(self.layers)):
            str+=f"LAYER {i}:\n\n{self.layers[i]}\n"
        return str

    def save(self, path):
        with open(path+".pickle", "wb") as outfile:
            pickle.dump(self, outfile)
    
    def load(path):
        with open(path+".pickle", "rb") as infile:
            return pickle.load(infile)

The code below is the actual training of the MLP
from NeuralNet import MLP
import csv
import time

def main():
    net = MLP(784, [200, 80], 10, activation=[MLP.tanh, MLP.sigmoid, MLP.sigmoid], loss=MLP.mean_square)
    # net = MLP.load("network")

    # train
    start = time.time()
    try:
        with open("MNISTdata/mnist_train.csv") as file:
            train_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
            v = 0
            for epoch in range(3):
                for row in train_data:
                    num = [0 for i in range(10)]
                    num[int(row[0])] = 1
                    
                    pixels = [int(pixel) for pixel in row[1:]]

                    # forward pass
                    net.forward(input=pixels, label=num)

                    # backward pass
                    net.backward(learning_rate=0.1)

                    v+=1
                    print(f"{v} Loss: {net.loss}")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')

    # test
    try:
        with open("MNISTdata/mnist_test.csv") as file:
            test_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            for row in test_data:
                num = int(row[0])
                
                pixels = [int(pixel) for pixel in row[1:]]

                distribution = net.run(input=pixels)
                predicted = distribution.index(max(distribution))
                
                if(num==predicted):
                    correct+=1
                total+=1

                print(correct, total)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        
    print(f"Accuracy: {correct/total * 100}%")
    
    net.save("network")

    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I tested my code with test samples and did the math to make sure forward and backward propagation are all working with the correct gradient descent values being calculated. The only problem is that when I attempt to train with MNIST, the maximum accuracy I could get is around 40% with 784 inputs(pixels) and 2 hidden layers with 200 and 80 neurons and then 10 neurons for output. It has the following activation functions performed in the order they are listed: tanh, sigmoid, sigmoid. It also uses the mean square loss function.

Not an expert but is 2 hidden layers enough? It doesn’t sound like enough to be classified a deep neural network, so wondering if that’s enough hidden layers for accurate digit recognition?

I was thinking the same thing before but when I added more and more hidden layers it stayed somewhat the same. 40% accuracy with 2 hidden layers is the best I could get it to.

Hmm… I assume you’re working from a published DNN architecture proven to do well classifying digits so you have the right activation functions, etc.? If so it could be a coding error unless it just takes a crazy long time to train on your hardware? I’ve never done this myself so just guessing.

From my research, everything I have done is standard for DNN architecture; however, you are right in the sense that it takes an insane amount of time to train as it is pretty inefficient. I just wanted to know if that was the issue resulting in the inaccurate MLP or if there something wrong code wise.

I’ll leave it to others to review the code—I’m a developer but have never coded my own self-trained DNN so I’m not the right person to do that check.
